# Loop for multiple series of inputs in Linux using Bash script

Tags: loops

Hi i am newly engaged with linux and scripting. I am trying to use a program where 2 or more input files are required. But i have more then 1100 file for each type of input. I have tried for a loop. But it didnt work. I have tried like as following :

#!/bin/bash

for file1 in *.aln.out;
for file2 in *.cds_accept.fa;
do
/mnt/genome3/Lab_Users/Kishor/DISK_2/softwares/trimal-1.4.1/source/trimal -in ${file1} -out ${file1}.trim -automated1 -backtrans ${file2}

here i am receving a error like " trimal.sh: line 4: `for file2 in *.cds_accept.fa;' ". it will be helpful for me if i can get some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Each `for` needs a `do` and a `done`.

```
for file1 in *.aln.out
do  for file2 in *.cds_accept.fa
    do /mnt/genome3/Lab_Users/Kishor/DISK_2/softwares/trimal-1.4.1/source/trimal -in ${file1} -out ${file1}.trim -automated1 -backtrans ${file2}
    done
done
```